# Equivalente do mysql_result no PDO

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, pdo

Estou a tentar passar de mysql para pdo mas nao entendo como passo aquele mysql_result para pdo, agradeço qualquer ajuda disponibilizada

```
$limite = 10;
$SQL_COUNT = mysql_query("SElECT COUNT('id') FROM anuncios WHERE categoria='$categoria' AND estado=1");
$SQL_RESULT = ceil(mysql_result($SQL_COUNT, 0) / $limite);
$pg = (isset($_GET["pg"])) ? (int)$_GET["pg"] : 1;
$start = ($pg -1) * $limite;
```

Comment: **Não testei** mas supondo que você já tem a PDO configurada tente o seguinte: `$limite = 10;
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SElECT COUNT('id') FROM anuncios WHERE categoria=:categoria AND estado=1");
$stmt->bindValue(':categoria', $categoria);
$stmt->execute();
$result = ceil($stmt->fetchColumn() / $limite);
$pg = (isset($_GET["pg"])) ? (int)$_GET["pg"] : 1;
$start = ($pg -1) * $limite;`

Comment: Falou em configurar PDO, eu nao configurei nada, é necesaria algum aconfiguração no xampp ou num qualquer servidor de alohamento online?

Comment: Sim, você precisa habilitar duas extensões no seu `php.ini {extension=php_pdo.dll - extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll}` e depois estabelecer sua conexão onde desejar `($con = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=exercicio", "root", "senha"); )` Neste site você pode encontrar mais informações caso tenha dúvidas: http://ademir.winponta.com.br/php-pdo-mysql-carregando-configurando/

Comment: Obrigado pela informação, so tenho de configurar no caso utilizar servidor local, quando fizer upload do site para um alojamento, tenho de efectuar alteração ou os servidores normais suportam pdo?

Comment: Acredito que praticamente todos aceitem PDO. Caso contrário você pode entrar em contato com o suporte da hospedagem escolhida para maiores informações...

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pela ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Em PDO podes obter o resultado da contagem da seguinte forma:

```php
$sql = "SElECT COUNT('id') FROM anuncios WHERE categoria=:categoria AND estado=1"; 

$result = $con->prepare($sql); 

$result->execute(array(':categoria' => $categoria)); 

$contagem = $result->fetchColumn();

echo $contagem;
```

O apresentado em cima pode ainda ser sintetizado para o em baixo apresentado se não estivermos a lidar com dados do usuário:

```php
$sql = "SElECT COUNT('id') FROM anuncios WHERE categoria='bubu' AND estado=1"; 

$contagem = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchColumn(); 

echo $contagem;
```

Comment: Ok, muito obrigado pela ajuda