# Transformando este código em PDO

Tags: query, pdo

queria transformar esta query em PDO,como fazer?

```
include 'config.php';

extract($_POST);
$user_ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// check if the user has already clicked on the unlike (rate = 2) or the like (rate = 1)
    $dislike_sql = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE ip = "'.$user_ip.'" and id_item = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 2 ');
    $dislike_count = mysql_result($dislike_sql, 0); 

    $like_sql = mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM  wcd_yt_rate WHERE ip = "'.$user_ip.'" and id_item = "'.$pageID.'" and rate = 1 ');
    $like_count = mysql_result($like_sql, 0); 

if($act == 'like'): //if the user click on "like"
    if(($like_count == 0) && ($dislike_count == 0)){
        mysql_query('INSERT INTO wcd_yt_rate (id_item, ip, rate )VALUES("'.$pageID.'", "'.$user_ip.'", "1")');
    }
    if($dislike_count == 1){
        mysql_query('UPDATE wcd_yt_rate SET rate = 1 WHERE id_item = '.$pageID.' and ip ="'.$user_ip.'"');
    }

endif;
if($act == 'dislike'): //if the user click on "like"
    if(($like_count == 0) && ($dislike_count == 0)){
        mysql_query('INSERT INTO wcd_yt_rate (id_item, ip, rate )VALUES("'.$pageID.'", "'.$user_ip.'", "2")');
    }
    if($like_count == 1){
        mysql_query('UPDATE wcd_yt_rate SET rate = 2 WHERE id_item = '.$pageID.' and ip ="'.$user_ip.'"');
    }

endif;
```

Comment: Você quer saber como fa? Já tem perguntas sobre isto aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56643/mysql-para-pdo-duvida, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/63114/alterar-um-select-mysql-para-um-select-pdo, certamente tem outras se procurar nas *tags*. Quer que façam para você? Aí acho que não é adequado para o este site.

Comment: se foi você que fez esse código com mysql eu sugiro que procure por tutoriais de pdo e/ou video aulas.

Comment: Pode ver o que cada comando faz nessa [pergunta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68232/91)