# Sistema De Freqüência | Converter Para PDO ou MYSQLI

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

Será que tem como converter esses codigos mysql para PDO ou MYSQLI, Me Ajudem Por Favor :(

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<link href="css/fazer_chamada.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
<? require "topo.php"; ?>
<div id="caixa_preta">
</div><!-- caixa_preta -->

<div id="box">
 <h1>Abaixo está mostrando todos os alunos do(a) <strong><? echo $curso = $_GET['curso']; ?></strong> Data de Hoje <strong><? echo date("d/m/Y"); ?></strong></h1>
 <?
 
 $date_hoje = date("d/m/Y");
 $date = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
 
 $sql_1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM estudantes WHERE serie = '$curso'");
 $conta_sql_1 = mysql_num_rows($sql_1);
 if($conta_sql_1 == ''){
  echo "<h2>Não existe nenhum aluno cadastro nesta disciplina!</h2>";
 }else{
    while($res_1 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_1)){
  $code_aluno = $res_1['code'];
  $nome = $res_1['nome'];
        
?>
<form name="button" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
<table width="955" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="94"><strong>Código:</strong></td>
    <td width="466"><strong>Nome:</strong></td>
    <td colspan="2"><strong>Este aluno está presente?</strong></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><? echo $res_1['code']; ?><input type="hidden" name="code_aluno" value="<? echo $res_1['code']; ?>" /></td>
    <td><? echo $res_1['nome']; ?><input type="hidden" name="nome" value="<? echo $res_1['nome']; ?>" /></td>
    <td width="315">
    
    <?
 $dis = $_GET['dis'];
    $sql_2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chamadas_em_sala WHERE date_day = '$date_hoje' AND code_aluno = '$code_aluno' AND disciplina = '$dis'");
 $conta_sql_2 = mysql_num_rows($sql_2);
 if($conta_sql_2 == ''){
 ?>
    <input type="radio" name="presensa" id="radio" value="SIM">
    <label for="radio">SIM 
      <input type="radio" name="presensa" value="NÃO">
    </label> 
    NÃO 
    <input type="radio" name="presensa" value="JUSTIFICADA">
    FALTA JUSTIFICADA 
    <label for="fileField"></label></td>
    <td width="62"><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Guardar"></td>
    <? }else{ echo "Indisponível"; } ?>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
<? }} ?>


<? if(isset($_POST['button'])){

$code_aluno = $_POST['code_aluno']; 
$nome = $_POST['nome']; 
$date_hoje = date("d/m/Y");
$date = date("d/m/Y H:i:s");
$dis = $_GET['dis'];
$presensa = $_POST['presensa'];


if($presensa == ''){
 echo "<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Por favor, informe se este aluno está presente ou não na sala de aula!');</script>";
}else{

$sql_3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM confirma_entrada_de_alunos WHERE data_hoje = '$date_hoje' AND code_aluno = '$code_aluno'");
$conta_sql_3 = mysql_num_rows($sql_3);
if($conta_sql_3 == '' && $presensa == 'SIM'){
 echo "<script language='javascript'>window.alert('Este aluno não entrou na escola hoje!');</script>";
}else{
$sql_4 = mysql_query("INSERT INTO chamadas_em_sala (date, date_day, curso, disciplina, code_professor, code_aluno, presente) VALUES ('$date', '$date_hoje', '$curso', '$dis', '$code', '$code_aluno', '$presensa')");
    echo "<script language='javascript'>window.location='';</script>";

 }}}?>

</div><!-- box -->

<? require "rodape.php"; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sim é possível, acredite!. Teve algum problema especifico ou erro?

Comment: [Transformando este código em PDO](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/80821/91)

Comment: Não, Porque, Estou Migrando Para o PDO. Enfim hoje estou voado para programa, mais é possível? poderia ajudar me no código?